# Sharing Records owned by community users

Tags: sharing

In my system i have requirement where i need to share records of particular object with different roles in round robin fashion.
I am doing this with the help of trigger. Now the problem i am facing is sharing records created by community users. In community we can share the records to roles but problem is whichever role or user is there added in community Share Group Settings tab it is shared with them all.
I want to share 1 record with 1 role only according to my round robin sharing.

Now is there any approach to do this, if no what else can be done, creating duplicate records and share them or any other good approach.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful. You've not told us what kind of community you have (customer, partner, etc?) or what kind of sharing you're currently using. What roles are you speaking of? Internal User Roles? Unless this is a Partner Community, Community Users don't have Roles.

Comment: @crmprogdev sry sir for the same!! community is customer community and roles i am talking is internal roles. i know community users dont have roles but thats what i need to implement, if this is not possible any other aprroach to do this, either changing owner of records or creating some new records or anything else.

Comment: Have you reviewed the communities implementation guide?  I believe it answers all of your questions.  http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

Comment: Get your question updated so that it can be reopened & I'll respond to it. I have thoughts on how to implement a solution if @HomerJ link doesn't provide you with the info you need.

Comment: @crmprogdev i have made edits in my question. Please check.

Comment: Can you tell us what your current sharing model is for Community Users, Regular Users and the Object Records that you want to share (both in the Community and in your internal Org)? The "role" you want to share with is an internal user, correct? In saying that, do you mean that you want to share with everyone in that role, or only one internal user in that role? Is your round robin a queue where each internal user/queue member has a unique role assigned to them?